# YOLOv5 paging file too small

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

I am trying to train a YOLOv5 CNN on a custom dataset with around 10000 training examples, but I keep getting the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Malth\OneDrive - Aarhus Universitet\7. Semester\DL\YOLO\yolov5\train.py", line 20, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\Malth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 1455] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete. Error loading "C:\Users\Malth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

Right before the error occurs the program uses up the entirety of my pagefile of 30GB + 10GB of assigned RAM.

I am running train.py with the following command:

```
python train.py --rect --batch 16 --epochs 3 --data CCPDMini.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt
```

My python version is 3.9.2

My PyTorch version is 1.9.1+cu111

I have the following setup:
Intel Core i7-4790 CPU
16 GB RAM
RTX2070 8GB VRAM

I have already tried reducing the batch size and the number of dataloader workers, but to no awail

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the amount of virtual memory available through advanced system settings like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oh6dga-Oy10? I've come accross some people who adjust it to the maximum available, some adjusting it to 'system managed'. If it's using the entirety of your RAM is it possible to upgrade your RAM. I had the same issue and changing the amount of VRAM available through advanced system settings didn't help but upgrading my RAM fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912123/paging-file-too-small-for-this-operation-to-complete-error-when-attempting-to

Comment: facing the same thing for YOLOV8